# sqlalchemy not setting timestmap default

Tags: python, mysql, datetime, sqlalchemy

SQLAlchemy isn't respecting `default=datetime.datetime.utcnow` or `default=func.now()` (I've tried both) for `DateTime` columns.

**Python:**

```
class DataStuff(BASE): 
    """some data""" 
    __tablename__ = 'datastuff' 
    _id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True) 
    _name = Column(String(64)) 
    json = Column(sqlalchemy.UnicodeText()) 
    _timestamp = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
```

**MySQL:**

```
mysql> describe datastuff;
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| _id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| _name         | varchar(64)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| json          | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| _timestamp    | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation using `server_default` is the way to go when the desired action is to provide a default value on a column within the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/defaults.html

I ended up using `server_default` with the `func.now()` function instead of `default=datetime.datetime.utcnow`.

**New code:**

```
from sqlalchemy import func
_timestamp = Column(DateTime, server_default=func.now())
```

**Result:**

```
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| _timestamp    | datetime     | YES  |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
```

violá